# Binding 2 textures, only see 1

Tags: opengl, textures, glsl, glfw

i'm trying to bind 2 textures for my shader. But for some reason it always seems to take the last image that i defined. Am i doing something wrong?

```
GLuint textures[2];

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glGenTextures(2, textures);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
glfwLoadTexture2D("C:\\front.tga", GLFW_BUILD_MIPMAPS_BIT);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[1]);
glfwLoadTexture2D("C:\\reflect.tga", GLFW_BUILD_MIPMAPS_BIT);
```

In this case i see 'reflect.tga' for both the reflection and refraction in my shader...

```
const vec3 Xunitvec = vec3 (1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
const vec3 Yunitvec = vec3 (0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

uniform vec3  BaseColor;
uniform float Depth;
uniform float MixRatio;

// need to scale our framebuffer - it has a fixed width/height of 2048
uniform float FrameWidth;
uniform float FrameHeight;

uniform sampler2D EnvMap;
uniform sampler2D RefractionMap;

varying vec3  Normal;
varying vec3  EyeDir;
varying vec4  EyePos;
varying float LightIntensity;

void main (void)
{
    // Compute reflection vector
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(EyeDir, Normal);

    // Compute altitude and azimuth angles

    vec2 index;

    index.y = dot(normalize(reflectDir), Yunitvec);
    reflectDir.y = 0.0;
    index.x = dot(normalize(reflectDir), Xunitvec) * 0.5;

    // Translate index values into proper range

    if (reflectDir.z >= 0.0)
        index = (index + 1.0) * 0.5;
    else
    {
        index.t = (index.t + 1.0) * 0.5;
        index.s = (-index.s) * 0.5 + 1.0;
    }

    // if reflectDir.z >= 0.0, s will go from 0.25 to 0.75
    // if reflectDir.z <  0.0, s will go from 0.75 to 1.25, and
    // that's OK, because we've set the texture to wrap.

    // Do a lookup into the environment map.

    vec3 envColor = vec3 (texture2D(EnvMap, index));

    // calc fresnels term.  This allows a view dependant blend of reflection/refraction
    float fresnel = abs(dot(normalize(EyeDir), Normal));
    fresnel *= MixRatio;
    fresnel = clamp(fresnel, 0.1, 0.9);

   // calc refraction
   vec3 refractionDir = normalize(EyeDir) - normalize(Normal);

   // Scale the refraction so the z element is equal to depth
   float depthVal = Depth / -refractionDir.z;

   // perform the div by w
   float recipW = 1.0 / EyePos.w;
   vec2 eye = EyePos.xy * vec2(recipW);

   // calc the refraction lookup
   index.s = (eye.x + refractionDir.x * depthVal);
   index.t = (eye.y + refractionDir.y * depthVal);

   // scale and shift so we're in the range 0-1
   index.s = index.s / 2.0 + 0.5;
   index.t = index.t / 2.0 + 0.5;

   // as we're looking at the framebuffer, we want it clamping at the edge of the rendered scene, not the edge of the texture,
   // so we clamp before scaling to fit
   float recip1k = 1.0 / 2048.0;
   index.s = clamp(index.s, 0.0, 1.0 - recip1k);
   index.t = clamp(index.t, 0.0, 1.0 - recip1k);

   // scale the texture so we just see the rendered framebuffer
   index.s = index.s * FrameWidth * recip1k;
   index.t = index.t * FrameHeight * recip1k;

    vec3 RefractionColor = vec3 (texture2D(RefractionMap, index));

    // Add lighting to base color and mix
    vec3 base = LightIntensity * BaseColor;
    envColor = mix(envColor, RefractionColor, fresnel);
    envColor = mix(envColor, base, 0.2);

    gl_FragColor = vec4 (envColor, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: What does your shader look like?

Comment: @user1118321 Added the code of my fragment shader.

Comment: I'm not seeing any of the obvious things wrong with it. How are you setting the uniform locations of sampler variables? (For example, what's your call to `glUniform1i (envMapLoc, 0);` look like?)

Comment: @user1118321 Well, actually i didn't get the uniform locations for the samplers, because i thought i didn't need to for textures. I just tried to implement it with glUniformli. But its still showing 1 texture instead of two. So i guess i'm still doing it wrong. I've pasted the part of my code where i set all the uniforms and the textures: http://pastebin.com/0S2iYBB2 --- Any idea what i'm doing wrong there..??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A sampler uniform does not bind a texture object but a texture unit. And texture objects are bound to texture units. So the sequence for binding a texture to a shader is

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + texture_unit1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_..., texture_object1);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + texture_unit2);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_..., texture_object2);


glUniform1i(sampler1_location, texture_unit1);
glUniform1i(sampler2_location, texture_unit2);
```

Texture Units are in the range 0...`GL_MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS`.

Comment: Great, thanks alot. Its working good now :) Can't vote up though because of my rep :-(

Comment: Note: You can't pass `glUniform1i` the same value you use for `glActiveTexture`. `glActiveTexture` takes an enum, while `glUniform1i` takes a texture unit index. So generally, this looks like `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + texture_unit1); ... glUniform1i(sampler1_location, texture_unit1);`